# Can't seem to access Session values in module's API file

Tags: api, session

I can't seem to access session values on API definition. `var_dump($_SESSION)` returns an empty array event after putting `session_start()`.

`api/v3/MymoduleEntity.php`

```
function civicrm_api3_mymodule_entity_method($params) {
  session_start();
  return var_dump($_SESSION); // Returns an empty array
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

-- Variable to set in CiviCRM session 

`CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->set('myVariable', 'Yes, I am in current Session');`

-- get value of variable from CiviCRM Session

`CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->get('myVariable');`

HTH
Pradeep